# Searching for URLS in string and add query string to each one problem

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

**I wrote this script to do this but there is an issue I couldn't figure out:**

```
$buffer = '<a href="http://wwww.domain.com">Domain1</a>';
$buffer .= '<a href="http://wwww.domain.com?id=2">Domain2</a>';

preg_match_all('/<a href="(.*?)"/s', $buffer, $matches);

$searches = array();
$replaces = array();

foreach($matches[1] as $link){

    $contain = parse_url($link, PHP_URL_QUERY);

    $symbol = $contain ? "&" : "?";

    $new_link = $link . $symbol . "mode=testing";

    $searches[] = $link;

    $replaces[] = $new_link;

}
$newbuffer = str_replace($searches ,$replaces , $buffer);

var_dump($newbuffer);
```

Output:

```
<a href="http://wwww.domain.com?mode=testing">Domain1</a>
<a href="http://wwww.domain.com?mode=testing?id=2">Domain2</a>
```

Expected Output thats adding the parameter to each link:

```
<a href="http://wwww.domain.com?mode=testing">Domain1</a>
<a href="http://wwww.domain.com?id=2&mode=testing">Domain2</a>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from:

- `$searches` contains :

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(24) ""http://wwww.domain.com""
  [1]=>
  string(29) ""http://wwww.domain.com?id=2""
}
```

- `$replaces` contains:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(37) ""http://wwww.domain.com?mode=testing""
  [1]=>
  string(42) ""http://wwww.domain.com?id=2&mode=testing""
}
```

Then `str_replace` replaces **all** elements from `$searches` to **all** elements from `$replaces`, so, `http://wwww.domain.com` with `http://wwww.domain.com?mode=testing` **AND** `http://wwww.domain.com?id=2` with `http://wwww.domain.com?mode=testing?id=2` (it append `?mode=testing` after `domain.com`)

Here is a solution:

Add `"` arround the links in both arrays.

```php
$buffer = '<a href="http://wwww.domain.com">Domain1</a>';
$buffer .= '<a href="http://wwww.domain.com?id=2">Domain2</a>';

preg_match_all('/<a href="(.*?)"/s', $buffer, $matches);

$searches = array();
$replaces = array();

foreach($matches[1] as $link){
    $contain = parse_url($link, PHP_URL_QUERY);
    $symbol = $contain ? "&" : "?";
    $new_link = $link . $symbol . "mode=testing";
    $searches[] = '"' . $link . '"';
    $replaces[] = '"' . $new_link . '"';
}
$newbuffer = str_replace($searches ,$replaces , $buffer);
var_dump($newbuffer);
```

**Output:**

```
<a href="http://wwww.domain.com?mode=testing">Domain1</a>
<a href="http://wwww.domain.com?id=2&mode=testing">Domain2</a>
```

Comment: Aww amazing @toto, its working perfectly !!, i spent 1 week trying to solve this problem :p